# Como colocar duas divs ao lado de um container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-3

Como faço para colocar duas divs, uma ao lado esquerdo e outra ao lado direito de uma container com o bootstrap? Sendo que gostaria que as divs laterais aumentem de tamanho conforme a tela.

Answer (score 8):

Creio que a resposta da sua pergunta está na utilização de 'fluid containers' ou seja, containers que ocuparão 100% da largura disponível no layout.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">ESQUERDO</div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div class="container-fluid">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">DIREITO</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mas Paulo faltou a div central e ela tem que ser um container.

Comment: fiz a alteração... veja se é isso ;)

Comment: mas eu não vejo motivos para um container dentro de outro container

Comment: Sim mas eu preciso, só que colocando uma coluna a container fica no tamanho da coluna e nao no tamanho de um container, entede?

Comment: faz um desenho do layout.. aí a gente mata

Comment: Esperar eu sair do trampo :P aí eu faço.

Answer (score 3):

Pelo o que eu entendi você precisa de três colunas, uma a direita, outra a esquerda, com um `.container`central, certo?
Dê uma olhada no html que fiz e veja se é isto.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eppQPM

Comment: Único problema é que o container não dentro da coluna não tem o mesmo tamanho de um container fora.